# Copying from GVIM to Windows doesn't work

Tags: vim

I have both gvim and vim running on my linux machine through vnc. GVIM opens a separate display terminal for each file. I can copy between gvim and vim. Also, from vim to windows. But copying from gvim to windows doesn't work.

I can copy by selecting the text and pasting using right-click. Not very much .vimrc expert, i would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not your VNC preventing copy/paste from the local and distant machine? I've already seen this kind of behaviour in the past.

Howeaver, in VIM I'd say it's because you have set your mouse to all (**:set mouse=a**) so you loose the copy/paste abilities of your OS so you can select/copy/paste with vim buffer instead.

With gVIM I'm not sure. Have you try do disable the mouse (**:set mouse=**) you should have access to a contextual menu.

(but my #1 guess is about your VNC limitations!)

Comment: I tried disabling mouse. I can copy paste only once. I wonder with the VNC limitations, because I had this is working flawless for more than a year. Not sure if something got updated within VNC and ruined my stuff

Answer (score 0):

Select the text using <kbd>v</kbd> and moving around. Then yank the text using

<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

you should be able to paste the text by right clicking the mouse.

Comment: copy paste works well inside the vnc. The problem is pasting it outside in windows. It just copy once.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on another site and it seems to fix the only being able to copy/paste once from gvim to windows. Close the current vncconfig window and relaunch with polling enabled (time in ms):

```
vncconfig poll=100 &
```